# A web interface (draggable elements, remembering state) similar to Wufoo

Tags: javascript, django, draggable, wufoo

The question I have is very specific. I wanted to have an app where I can create forms, as on Wufoo, with easy to use interface. Which means, draggable elements.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how will the state be saved in the database once the use changes the ordinal position of the form elements. I can do the front-end side, and there are libraries available for that but how do I save a particular instance of the form in the backend so that the next time use logs in, the order is same.

I would love to use Django for this app. So, the basic classes I can think of are:

```
class Form(models.Model):
  """...objects..."""


class TextField(models.Model):
  """...objects..."""
  #FK to Form()


class TitleArea(models.Model):
  """...objects..."""
  #FK to Form()
```

I can also have specific ID's on the elements in the HTML form:

```
<input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="text"/>
```

How do they (Wufoo) do this? Is my Model not correct? I know it is naive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hidden input fields for the win.

suppose:

```
$("#submitForm").click(function() {
    // Check out the state of the union and change the hidden fields accordingly..
    // Something like:
    for (var i = 0; i < $(".orderedElements").length; i++) {
        $("#ordered-" + ((Number) i + 1)).attr('value', $(".orderedElements").eq(i).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

If you catch my drift.

Comment: I see. So, I have to have a field in each of the Elements' class?  something like: `ordinal_position = models.IntegerField(...)` ? .. and it might change (via AJAX) every time user grads the element up or down...(?)

Comment: I don't know django so zeekay solution might be more suitable but regardless your programming language, you can use my solution. Whenever you 'submit' or 'save' the hidden input fields are sent to the server and their order is stored in the db, and when you present the page again just extract the elements order from the db and place them accordingly.

Comment: Sure. Whenever a user submits or saves the form you look for every section and find where it is ordered, you then push that value into hidden form feeds. e.g., the first hidden input's value will be 'element3' and then you can save this to the db: first hidden input (first in order) equals element3. You can also use just one hidden input if you think about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ModelForm`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to create forms using a model instance. Just save the model after a user is done editing, and then when you create the form for them again use the model as an instance to your `ModelForm` (or formset):

```
form = YourForm(instance=model_instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a good place to start is to think about a use-case.  If I'm a user, what am I going to need available to me, to build a form?  Textfields, sure -- but what else?  Is the form going to have a title?  A URL?  An expiration date?

When you have this kind of information plotted out, then you can start building out your models in Django.